# stdio.h not found after migrating to xcode5

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, build-process, xcode5

I had a iOS project based on c/c++ files. So far i was working on X code 4.6.3. Recently i encountered an error related to voice recording.The solution suggested was to move to x code 5. and fix it.

when i upgraded to x code 5. Suddenly the project started giving error saying "stdio.h" is not found.

I tried deleting and installing X code again, as was suggested in many posts. Still it gives the same error.

Checked that command line tools are installed. X code install it every time i download it again.

I also tried to fiddle with Xcode Build settings for Apple LLVM 5.0 Custom Compiler Flags, Language, Language-C++, Language-Modules, Language-Objective C.
Since this is such a basic header file. I am assuming that i m missing out something very trivial.

**Question**: where do I find `stdio.h` when compiling for iOS? Or what header should I use in place of `stdio.h` to ensure my program compiles?

Comment: Thanks for reply,but No its the not the issue of duplicate i checked that.

Comment: I'm not an iOS developer, but if you are writing C++ code, have you tried to use <cstdio> instead?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install command line tool in the preferences inside components of your new installed X-code? If not then please click there on install button.
And after that try to run this command:-

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/
```

Comment: Well, he explicitly mentioned that the command line tools are installed

Comment: Hussain and Martin thanks for reply, Your replies led me to think in different direction and i found out that somewhere the project was still pointing to iPhoneOS6.1.sdk. Which is not available with Xcode 5.I got error like this "clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk'" The one solution i was able to figure out was to get iPhoneOS6.1.sdk and paste it there. this made the project work but i am still not able to switch to iPhoneOS7.0.sdk. If anyone has any idea about that please let me know

Comment: To fix your specific problem, we need to see your compiler driver command.

Answer (score 0):

So, the Apple includes `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdio.h>` and friends. You have to ensure the headers are on path. You can find a selection of `<stdlib.h>`'s to use and their respective path with `find`:

```
$ find /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer -name stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
```

Here's two ways you can ensure the headers are on path. First (the preferred way) is to use `--sysroot`. Using `--sysroot` ensures both the header ***and*** libraries are on path, so you won't need additional compiler options (like `-I`, -`L`, `l`, etc):

```
CC=export CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -arch armv7 -arch armv7s \
    --sysroot="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk""
```

Then, you would use it like so:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c foo.c -o foo.o
```

The second way is to include only the headers, but you will experience similar pain points for libraries:

```
CC=export CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -arch armv7 -arch armv7s \
    -I="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include""
```

And you would still use it like so:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c foo.c -o foo.o
```

In my case, I was failing with a "no such file or directory" error. But it ***was not*** no such file `<stdio.h>` (which is what I read it to be). Rather, I saved a file using the keyboard: a <kbd>CTRL + S</kbd> missed the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, so my `--sysroot` was misspelled. It used `sdks` (plural dues to the extra `s`) rather than `sdk` (singular). So the SYSROOT directory was not correct.

And I started a bounty due to a mispelling....